# Different Multi-dimension concat in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, reshape, concatenation, convolution

I need to concat these tensors in the dimensions 2 and 3:

```
[<tf.Tensor 'one' shape=(3, 3, 15, 30) dtype=float32>, 
<tf.Tensor 'two' shape=(3, 3, 14, 29) dtype=float32>,
<tf.Tensor 'three' shape=(3, 3, 1, 1) dtype=float32>]
```

I know that in the space it makes no sense but I tried to to a reshape into:

```
[<tf.Tensor 'one' shape=(3, 3, xx) dtype=float32>, 
<tf.Tensor 'two' shape=(3, 3, yy) dtype=float32>,
<tf.Tensor 'three' shape=(3, 3, zz) dtype=float32>]
```

And then a concat:

```
[<tf.Tensor 'one' shape=(3, 3, xx+yy+zz) dtype=float32>]
```

Does it make sense? Anyone got some other idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use tf.concat with axis parameter set to 2.

```
x = [tensor1, tensor2, tensor3]
tf.concat(x, axis=2)
```

Comment: The thing is that I need the final array to be:

    [<tf.Tensor 'one' shape=(3, 3, 30, 60) dtype=float32>]

which is the concat of axis 2 and 3 and not:

    [<tf.Tensor 'one' shape=(3, 3, xx+yy+zz) dtype=float32>]